# Extracting ISO to location using 7zip in Linux

Tags: java, linux

So I am making an application which extracts iso to location (mainly usb mount point i.e /media/kp/mount_point)

**pzip-full** package is installed on my machine. So the relevant code for extracting iso from shell `sudo 7z x -y 'filename' -o'location'`. Sudo since I am extracting it to `/media/kp/mount_point` which requires root.

So in java I created a function as follows which runs the above 7z command as sudo with my sudo password and also logs and returns the output as String.

```
private String ExecuteShell(String command) {
    String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash","-c","echo 'mysudopass' | sudo -S "+command};
    StringBuilder joined= new StringBuilder();
    Process pb = null;
    try {
        pb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        String line;
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            joined.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return joined.toString();
}
```

Now running it as `ExecuteShell("7z x -y '"+filename+"' -o'"+location+"'")`;

**Here is the issue**, the command works fine when run from terminal but when I go with above function in Java it prints the output from 7zip as required but I don't see it written on my USB stick and it runs for only max 5 secs whereas my ISO is a big file should take atleast a min or 2.

I tried to change location as regular path like `/home/kp/Desktop/folder`. Here it extracts quickly with empty folders (only structure) with a lock & cross symbol on folder. See image

[image]

I don't know why it occurs I tried chmod +x and 777 on usb mount point and on iso file. Still it not works. Any reason why and how to resolve it?

Note: I am not just extracting iso file its just a file I am using for test. It will be used for many file types. That's why I don't want recommendation to use Loopy or java-iso-tools.

Edit: My code is perfect, the issue was with my `thread`. I was using two threads simultaneously writing on usb stick which makes the usb as resource used! That's why error. Sorry for wasting time! my code is perfect it's just me who played an idiot game.

Comment: Why are you writing Java to do this?

Comment: Writing in a cross-platform language.

Comment: It's all still Linux.  Otherwise how can you use `sudo` or `chmod`?

Comment: If you are executing `/bin/bash ... sudo ...`  from Java code, your program is limited to UNIX/Linux platforms that have `/bin/bash`, so you could write a shell script instead. Which command exactly do you successfully run from a terminal? If you use `sudo`, do you manually type the password? Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: sudo 7z x -y 'filename' -o'location' This one by typing password

Comment: Since you are only reading the standard output of the command and not even using `waitFor` on the command process object, you don't know if there are any errors in the command. I strongly suggest reading the standard error from the command and using `waitFor` to get the process return status.

Comment: There are no errors in the command and waitfor is returning 0 after it completes.

Comment: Please answer your own question with the solution and accept it as valid answer so that others, like me, do not come here to try and answer. Thanks